# Using "as" on my avr toolchain

Tags: avr

I am receiving errors when I try to cross-compile an assembly file in my terminal. Can someone explain to me why these errors occur?

Here is my assembly file:

```
.text
    .globl start
start:
jmp main

mboot:
 .set ALIGN,    1<<0
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS 
.long CHECKSUM
main:
call kernel_main
    cli
    hlt
```

I opened the terminal on my ubuntu 13.10 and entered:

```
avr-as kernel_start.asm -o kernel_start.o
```

and I get these errors:

```
kernel_start.asm: Assembler messages:
kernel_start.asm:4: Error: illegal opcode jmp for mcu avr2
kernel_start.asm:19: Error: illegal opcode call for mcu avr2
kernel_start.asm:21: Error: unknown opcode `hlt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HLT` is not an AVR instruction, which is why that's providing an error for unknown opcode.  If you want the equivalent of an infinite loop, you could write a line like `end: rjmp end`.

`JMP` is only available in at Xmega core, which isn't included in the generic model avr2.  Use `RJMP` instead.

It appears that `CALL` is also not supported by the avr2 model.  Use `RCALL` instead.

Comment: So what is the avr instruction for jmp? If there is no, how do I instruct it to jump?

Comment: rjmp main should get you what you want.  (rjmp is a relative jump with an offset from where you are now, but the assembler will take care of the details for you.)

Comment: What about hlt? Is there another way of saying that?

Comment: Well, what do you want it to do?  Just stop running completely?  There's no way to stop the core itself.  I suppose you could do a label `end: RJMP end` or something to infinitely loop.

Comment: I found a post online that said that infinite loops waste the CPU by making it go in circles executing code when it could have been resting with a "hlt" instruction. But I guess there is no other choice. Right?

Comment: The short answer is "No, there's no other choice in this case."

Comment: The AVR equivalent to `HLT` is called `SLEEP`. It must be enabled, however.

Answer (score 1):

Opcodes jmp and hlt are not available for all microcontrollers. Ensure your microcontroller can handle these instructions and that you are passing the proper parameters to the assembler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first thing to realize is that assembly is not one language; it is at least one language per processor family, frequently more, and with dialects on top. The code you posted seems related to [Multiboot](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html), which was designed for [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) and is likely not relevant on [AVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set), which is a family of 8-bit microcontrollers.

If we are to attempt porting the module, we need to understand the instructions, because even when instructions are named the same they may carry different meaning; an infamous example is [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10#Instructions) `JUMP` which meant *never* jump.

For AVRs in particular, due to their system on chip nature you are expected to set up the sleep mode intended before halting with `SLEEP`, and the unconditional jump is frequently trimmed down to only the relative `RJMP` because it can already reach the whole instruction memory. Models with more memory do have other options.

The type of bootloader Multiboot was written for is not generally used on AVR, as the intruction memory is normally a Flash EEPROM and there is no separate boot media. The jump instruction you had in `start` would reside in the reset interrupt vector, typically address 0. Many larger AVR chips have specific support for bootloaders, in the form of a simple memory region lock and second set of interrupt vectors, but since the program memory is non-volatile the bootloader is intended for firmware updates, not normal program starts.